How to test wheter a value is included in an array declared as const
I have an array as const:
const array = ['a', 'b'] as const;

Now I want to check if a value is in that array:
let variable = 'a';
if (array.includes(variable)) 

Typescript yields an error:

TS2345: Argument of type string is not assignable to parameter of type 'a' | 'b'

Which is correct. But how can I avoid it? I found the solutions:
if (array.includes(variable as typeof array[number]))
if ((array as unknown as string[]).includes(variable))

But both are not satisfying me because they are pretending something that is not true.
Does anybody know a better solution?


typing variable as const will infer that it's of type 'a', and thus compatible with the array
you don't need 15 casts, array is a readonly array, so you need to cast it to that e.g. array as readonly string[]


Casting to readonly string[] is most intuitive. It is easy to get mislead by the error message saying to cast to unknown.

Yes that definitely seems like something which should be reported to the compiler, it's a really bad suggestion for an error which I would assume is relatively common.

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/36404 looks a lot like this issue

Use as const might not be flexible for array value. Maybe do like this instead


  type Data = 'a' | 'b';
  const array: Data[] = ['a', 'b'];
  const variable = 'a';
  if (array.includes(variable)) {
    // do something
  }



Or


  const array: string[] = ['a', 'b'];
  const variable = 'a';
  if (array.includes(variable)){
    // do something
  }




In your first snippet, I have to write the values twice, which is bad practice, especially when there are more than 2 values. In the second snippet I don't have a type which I do need.

You could also consider using Array constructor together with a generic type, this would be an explicit definition.
type RangeValues = 'a' | 'b';

const array = new Array<RangeValues>('a','b');
let value: RangeValues = 'b';

if (array.includes(value)) {
    console.log('WILL BE REACHED');
}

